# Why do I need to use spring annotation in my controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, playframework

I'm new to play and also to spring. Started to work in a project and if I just create my controller class like this:

```
package controllers;

import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;

public class Users extends Controller {

    public Result login(){
        return ok(views.html.login.render());
    }

}
```

I got this exception:

```
[NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [controllers.Users] is defined]
```

[image]

But, if I insert this annoation from spring on the top level:

```
package controllers;

import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;

@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
public class Users extends Controller {

    public Result login(){
        return ok(views.html.login.render());
    }

}
```

The page is rendered. But I don't know why this is happening. I would like to use spring only when is necessary, work with play on its full capacity. So I wonder if I'm doing right using this annotation on my controller.

**EDIT:**

```
import configuration.WebAppConfig;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import play.Application;
import play.GlobalSettings;

/**
 * Application wide behaviour. We establish a Spring application context for the dependency injection system and
 * configure Spring Data.
 */
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

    /**
     * The name of the persistence unit we will be using.
     */
    static final String DEFAULT_PERSISTENCE_UNIT = "default";

    /**
     * Declare the application context to be used - a Java annotation based application context requiring no XML.
     */
    final private AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();

    /**
     * Sync the context lifecycle with Play's.
     */
    @Override
    public void onStart(final Application app) {
        super.onStart(app);

        // AnnotationConfigApplicationContext can only be refreshed once, but we do it here even though this method
        // can be called multiple times. The reason for doing during startup is so that the Play configuration is
        // entirely available to this application context.
        ctx.register(SpringDataJpaConfiguration.class);
        ctx.scan("controllers", "models");
        ctx.refresh();

        // This will construct the beans and call any construction lifecycle methods e.g. @PostConstruct
        ctx.start();

    }

    /**
     * Sync the context lifecycle with Play's.
     */
    @Override
    public void onStop(final Application app) {
        // This will call any destruction lifecycle methods and then release the beans e.g. @PreDestroy
        ctx.close();

        super.onStop(app);
    }

    /**
     * Controllers must be resolved through the application context. There is a special method of GlobalSettings that we
     * can override to resolve a given controller. This resolution is required by the Play router.
     */
    @Override
    public <A> A getControllerInstance(Class<A> aClass) {
        return ctx.getBean(aClass);
    }

    /**
     * This configuration establishes the Spring context which in our case is defined in the "other" project.
     */
    @Configuration
    @Import(WebAppConfig.class)
    public static class SpringDataJpaConfiguration {
        // At the moment this class is just a entry point for the "other project" Spring context config, AppContext
    }

}
```

**EDIT 2:**
Guys, now I remember something in this project, we have 2 projects, one developed entirely on `java` and `spring` and this one, the webapp. We are importing the `.jar` built from the first project on this project with play. We are doing like these so we don't have to maintain two different models.

Comment: What does the class `Global` look like?

Comment: Apparently you're mixing Play and Spring in a way they were not meant to. Impossible to know without seeing some code (at least the configuration). Are you wiring the `User` controller in some other place via Spring's `@Autowired`?

Comment: @kryger No, this controller is new, I just created some minutes ago. I just want to start working with. And I think the same, maybe we're mixing things with spring and play when we shouldn't.

Comment: @kryger Please take a look on my `EDIT 2` and see if that makes more sense, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your class `Global` you actually tell the Playframework to resolve controllers from the Spring application context:

```
@Override
public <A> A getControllerInstance(Class<A> aClass) {
    return ctx.getBean(aClass);
}
```

In this case it is clear, that you have to have Spring annotations on your controllers, otherwise they wouldn't be added to the application context. If you don't want to resolve controllers from the application context, remove that method. But keep in mind, that you will not be able to inject Spring components in your Play controllers then, since they are not managed by Spring.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It makes sense now! However I wonder if we're doing this correctly. On my view, the controller should be handled only by play and these injections from spring should be taken care of in the models. My point is that I think we should make these injection from Spring in the lowest level. But I might be wrong here.

Comment: That depends how you access the model. Every class, which uses injection, needs to be managed by Spring (some exceptions apply, but i would use these only when really necessary). So if your controller never uses any class, which uses injection, then you would be fine. Otherwise let Spring manage them.

Comment: Now thinking a little bit more clearly, these classes that are injected comes from a `.jar` file, is our first project which uses spring, so that's why it has been used like this, if I understood this whole issue right :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with IoC (Inversion of Control) and DI (Dependency Injection)?
[Spring IoC has a container](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html) It need to know every component. You must to configure it with configuration files/configuration classes, and annotations can be useful to avoid have a extensive configuration.

Comment: I don't know any of these David. Thank you very much for the reply! :)

Comment: This doesn't answer *why* a Play Framework controller is required to be annotated with Spring's annotation to be picked up.

Comment: @ValterHenrique Spring allows composition over inheritance easily.

Comment: @kryger You're right, but he said: _I'm new to play and also to spring_. From my point of view, is more important to understand the principles than a "magical" explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retreive a bean instance from Spring's context that bean [must be managed by Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html). Adding `@Controller` to your controller and enabling component scan pointing to its package (or superpackage) tells to Spring to create an instance of that class inside its context, an instance you could lately use.

Having said that, [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getBean-java.lang.Class-) is explained why you got that exception.